# How to change gvim titlestring

Tags: vim

I would like to change the default gvim title string

```
$FILENAME $MODIFIERS ($FILEDIR) - $VIMSERVER
```

into following

```
$VIMSERVER - $FILENAME $MODIFIERS ($FILEDIR)
```

However I'm not sure how to achieve that. I'm not so great with vim, so looking at `:help statusline` didn't help me a lot, I'm not sure how to get vimserver and filedir, there is only %F but I don't know how to cut of filename.

At the moment easiest option seems to just patch `buffer.c` to just produce what I want by default (I compile vim from source anyway), but I'm sure it should be possible without it.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add this line into your `vimrc`, it may help you:

```
set titlestring=%{v:servername}\ -\ %t\ %m\ (%{expand('%:p:h')})
```

Comment: Ha, amazing! Works like a charm.